# Как добавлять новые поля Django

Tags: python, html, django

Есть код модели

```
class Training(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    exc = models.CharField(max_length=512)
```

на сайте будет кнопка: "добавить упражнение"
и как сделать так, чтобы в модель добавлялось ещё одно поле, или столько полей, сколько упражнений добавит пользователь?

Comment: Не надо так делать. Надо делать упражнение моделью и для добавления нового упражнения создавать новые экземпляры этой модели

Comment: не понятна задача. у вас уже есть модель Training - вот пусть пользователь и плодит ее эксзмпляры

Comment: каким образом? я не понимаю

Comment: а, или добавить главную модель Training, и к ней ключами привязывать ещё модель Exc?

Comment: Ну типа того наверное https://metanit.com/python/django/5.6.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так

```
class Training(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    exc = models.ManyToManyField("Exercise")


сlass Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Название упражнения', max_length=256)
    description = models.TextField('Описание упражнения', default='')
```

Условно логика такая... Создаете набор упражнений, а потом собираете из них тренировку. ManyToManyField позволяет ассоциировать большое кол-во упражнение с одной тренировкой.

Вот тут [документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: А также позволяет ассоциировать большое кол-во тренировок с одним упражнением — не уверен, является ли это тем, чего хочет автор вопроса

Comment: Я предположил из вопроса "как сделать так, чтобы в модель добавлялось ещё одно поле, или столько полей, сколько упражнений добавит пользователь?", что автор хочет позволить добавлять упражнение к своей тренировке. Но если он хочет другого, полагаю автор нам это разъяснит

Comment: всё верно, мне подобное нужно было. Благодарю

Comment: ```
 name 'Exercise' is not defined
```
 получается такая ошибка, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: @Quick в том, что вы забыли его импортировать, например?

Comment: откуда мне его импортировать? если я его пишу в этом же коде, как выше код

Comment: @Quick а, это автор ответа ошибся, заверните верхний `"Exercise"` в кавычки

Comment: помогло! Это то что было нужно, благодарю

Comment: Да... Нужно либо класс Exercise определить выше Training, либо взять его в кавычки. Отредактировал ответ